# Javascript setTimeout function repeat

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Is there a way to repeat a function in Javascript using the setTimeout function? For example, I need two functions to be called every five seconds. I have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    setTimeout('shiftLeft(); showProducts();', 5000);    
});
```

but it only happens once, five seconds after page loads, and I need it to happen every five seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) instead of `setTimeout()`, if you want your function to be executed repeatedly. `setTimeout()` delays the execution of your function for x seconds, while `setInterval()` executes your function every x seconds.

<sup>Both within the boundaries of the event queue of JavaScript, so don't be too confident, that you functions get executed at the exact time you specified</sup>

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    setInterval( function(){ shiftLeft(); showProducts(); }, 5000);    
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I chose the faster answer, but I voted up your answer

Answer (score 2):

Every x seconds can be done with `setInterval`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  setInterval(function(){
    shiftLeft(); showProducts();
  }, 5000);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  setTimeout(function(){
    shiftLeft(); showProducts();
  }, 5000);    
});
```