# Running SetTimeout recursively in Chrome Console?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript setTimeout function repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268385/javascript-settimeout-function-repeat)

I press CTRl-SHIFT-J to get to the console. I then type in:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { alert(1985); } , 1000);
```

It executes the alert once, and then the output shows:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { alert(2); } , 1000);
4
```

I.e. Some number afterwards. But it does not repeat the alert and pop up a 2 every second as I want it to. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not calling `setTimeout` recursively (you are just calling `alert`) and it will execute the callback only *once* after the given timeout. The number the console shows is the return value of `setTimeout` and is the ID of that timeout (so that you can cancel it).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` - one time 
 `setInterval` - repeated