# Repeat the function for every 1 min?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, function, onclick

i am calling a function with parameters from onclick method what i want to do is i want this function to repeat every 1 min here is html code:
I am calling a function on everyclick with some parameter as id
The id fetches the the lat longs,and it is plotted in map ,i have done everything working except that i get the data keep recieving from the back end so what i want to do is , as i have clicked the href i want that particular id to be sent and keep recieve the data of that particular id only and when i click the second the first should be stopped and start the another .

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="todo(1)"></a>
    <a href="#" onclick="todo(2)"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
function todo(id)
{
    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "example?value="+id,
            dataType:"text",
            success: function(data) 
            {
             //parsing;
            });
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the javascript `setInterval()` method yet?

Comment: Are there any constraints like do not repeat on error, only repeat if previous call has completed?

Comment: see i have edited what if i have 2 function calls with different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Use setInterval to call function every 1 minute and "trigger" function to click automatically when call function "test"

```
    <html>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="todo" onclick="todo(1)">sdsd</a>
   <a href="#" class="todo" onclick="todo(2)">sdsd</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    function todo(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "example?value="+id,
                dataType:"text",
                success: function(data) 
                {
                 //parsing;
                });
    }
    function test() {
    $(".todo").trigger("click");
    }
    var refreshId = setInterval(test, 60000);
```

Comment: what if i have 2 function call with different parameters??

Comment: use same class like "todo" its call every 1 min

Comment: I have update my answer and add same class for in a tag

Comment: i tried this and guess what 2 functions run :P how can i make it to run only 1 at a time???

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call a `setInterval` inside your `todo` function and it will fire with different calls, change your function like this:

```js
function todo(id) {
  setInterval(function() {
    /*$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "example?value=" + id,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          //parsing;
        });*/
    console.log(id);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="todo(1)">link1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="todo(2)">link2</a>
```

I used only `1000` milliseconds for test here, you only have to change it to `60000` to fit your needs, you can see the results in the console..

**Note:**

Keep in mind that for each click you will fire a new `setInterval()` so you have to disable click events after the first `setInterval()` to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear as to what constraints you may require from your question and comments, but perhaps something like this?

Repeat will be stopped if there is an ajax error.

Clicking a button will cancel the current repeat and immediately start the new repeat (1-4). Requests in progress are not cancelled and there is no checking included to ignore processing them upon complete.

A stop button is included, this will stop the repeat but not the request in progress.

The requests are async and no effort has been made to make sure that they are processed in order of request.

This is a very basic example that starts you moving in the right direction.

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('out'),
    interval = 5,
    running = false,
    fetching = false,
    timerId;

function stop() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    running = false;
}

function todo(id) {
    fetching = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?id=' + id,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            pre.textContent += id + ': ' + textStatus + '\n';
            stop();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            pre.textContent += id + ': ' + data[0].title + '\n';
        },
        complete: function () {
            fetching = false;
        }
    });
}

function start(id) {
    if (running) {
        stop();
    }

    running = true;
    if (!fetching) {
        todo(id);
    }

    timerId = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fetching) {
            todo(id);
        }
    }, interval * 1000);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
    
    if (target.classList.contains('album')) {
        start(target.value);
    }
}, false);

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function () {
    stop();
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="album" value="1">1</button>
<button class="album" value="2">2</button>
<button class="album" value="3">3</button>
<button class="album" value="4">4</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout of javascript.
It will repeat given function in specified time interval.

[Javascript setTimeout function repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268385/javascript-settimeout-function-repeat)

OR

```
setInterval( function(){ todo(id);}, 60000);
```

Comment: what about the parameter?

Comment: Please refer link in answer. It has been edited now.

Comment: 5000 should be 60000.

Comment: i tried but will this work for 2 href's with same function call?

Comment: You can clear timeout of first call and then call same function with different id in setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `setTimeout` to call the function again:

```
function todo(id)
{
    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "example?value="+id,
            dataType:"text",
            success: function(data) 
            {
             //parsing;
            });
    setTimeout(function(){todo(id)}, 60000);
}
```

And if you also want to clear timeout on some condition:

```
var timer;
function todo(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "example?value="+id,
                dataType:"text",
                success: function(data) 
                {
                 //parsing;
                });
        timer = setTimeout(function(){todo(id)}, 60000);
        if(//Your condition){
         window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
```